# Generic type lambda function argument as a function argument

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following code. Ideally `onPreferenceChange: (Preferences.Key) -> Unit` is what I would use to call the viewModel function which would assume the generic type of Preferences.Key with the type of value. However, this gives the following error: `One type argument expected for class Key<T>`

The easy way could be to pass the viewModel as parameter of ScreenBody, but this seems to be not recommended by the guidelines (the child should pass events to the parent(s)) and breaks the Composable preview

EDIT: The type of Preferences.Key<> can be String, Boolean, Int, Double, Set

How could I proceed here?

```
@Composable
fun SettingsScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: SettingsScreenViewModel = viewModel(factory = ViewModelProvider.Factory),
) {
    Scaffold {
        SettingsScreenBody(
            onPreferenceChange = viewModel::setPreferenceValue,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun SettingsScreenBody(
    onPreferenceChange: (key: Preferences.Key, value: Any) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
        // App Theme
        ListPreference(
            title = R.string.pref_title_app_theme,
        ) { newValue ->
            onPreferenceChange(PreferenceRepository.Keys.NIGHT_MODE, newValue)
        }
}

class SettingsScreenViewModel(
    private val preferenceRepository: PreferenceRepository,
): ViewModel() {

    val preferences = preferenceRepository.preferences

    fun <T> setPreferenceValue(key: Preferences.Key<T>, value: T) {
        viewModelScope.launch { preferenceRepository.set(key, value) }
    }

}

object Keys {
    val NIGHT_MODE: Preferences.Key<String> = stringPreferencesKey("night_mode")
    val METRIC_UNITS: Preferences.Key<Boolean> = booleanPreferencesKey("metric_units")
    // other keys of Int and Double types
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing around the code [as suggested by CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77932630/1354096), I found an acceptable workaround. Seems like the solution is to use a function body instead of passing a function reference so that the code results in the following (posting only code affected by the changes, rest of the code remains the same):

```
@Composable
fun SettingsScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: SettingsScreenViewModel = viewModel(factory = ViewModelProvider.Factory),
) {
    Scaffold {
        SettingsScreenBody(
            onPreferenceChange = { key, value ->                           //
                viewModel.setPreferenceValue(key, value)                   // CHANGE 1
            },                                                             //
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
        )
    }
}


@Composable
private fun SettingsScreenBody(
    onPreferenceChange: (key: Preferences.Key<*>, value: Any) -> Unit,     // CHANGE 2
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    // App Theme
    ListPreference(
        title = R.string.pref_title_app_theme,
    ) { newValue ->
        onPreferenceChange(PreferenceRepository.Keys.NIGHT_MODE, newValue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is your current lambda declaration:

```kotlin
onPreferenceChange: (key: Preferences.Key, value: Any) -> Unit
```

This is your one-and-only use of that lambda:

```kotlin
onPreferenceChange(PreferenceRepository.Keys.NIGHT_MODE, newValue)
```

Assuming normal naming conventions, `NIGHT_MODE` is a `final` value, and it has a specific type. I do not know what it is, as you did not include it in the question, but let's assume that it is a `Preferences.Key<String>`.

You can change your lambda to:

```kotlin
onPreferenceChange: (key: Preferences.Key<String>, value: Any) -> Unit
```

That will then satisfy the requirements of `Preferences.Key`, which is a generic type and needs a declaration.

You could experiment with:

```kotlin
onPreferenceChange: (key: Preferences.Key<*>, value: Any) -> Unit
```

but I don't know what value that would add, and I'm unconvinced that it will play nicely with your actual implementation of `onPreferenceChange`.

Comment: That would be correct as the one-and-only use is the String type (as the example is), but in real code it could be possible to use Int, Boolean, Double, String and even Set so that solution won't apply. Will update the question to add this. I also tried with <*> and <Any>, but I always end up in a similar error, most of the cases related to Kotlin type erasure

Comment: @BamsBamx: OK, have you tried declaring it with `<T>` akin to your viewmodel: `private fun <T> SettingsScreenBody(
    onPreferenceChange: (key: Preferences.Key<T>, value: T) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
)`?

Comment: I tried too, but since this function is a Composable, seems like it's not the way. In addition, this wouldn't work since in SettingsScreen I would have to call SettingsScreenBody with a type, which would break the other types (e.g. if I used String, I couldnt use other types anymore)

Comment: Seems like it's a kotlin problem related to losing generic type function information when using the function as a lambda